# Late 2012 iMac not seeing Bootcamp 6 update

Tags: imac, bootcamp, windows

I would like to install Windows 10 and use Bootcamp 6 to do so on a 2012 iMac. According to Apple's documentation, this should have appeared and been installed by software update. When I check my Bootcamp version though, it is 5.1.4. I have updated everything on the actual computer (10.10.5, etc).

They used to provide access to the direct PKG files to install, but I don't see one for bootcamp 6.

What am I doing wrong. According to their support document, this machine should be supported - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990

Comment: Same here with Bootcamp 5 and Windows 10 on Late 2012 MPB... :(

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7177436) on Apple Support Communities, the version number "6" only shows up in Windows, or in XML files on the Mac, if you go digging.

From what I understand, you should be able to, without any problems, use a Windows 10 ISO with the 5.1.4 version of Bootcamp Assistant, and it'll be smart enough to download the version 6 drivers behind the scenes.